# Changing Django language code on the links

Tags: django, internationalization

(i18n) The ISO language code for Kazakh language uses kk I want to change it to kz in my project to make it convenient for people in Kazakhstan who used to be use kz in links.
As example I need to be able instead to www.mydomain.com/kk use www.mydomain.com/kz

Answer (score 1):

You can use this lines in your settings.py:

```
LANGUAGES = [
    ('kz', _('Kazakh')),
    ('en', _('English')),
]
```

and you should add your locale path to `LOCALE_PATHS` like this:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale')
]
```

and you should make po file and mo file in locale folder. for example: `locale/kz/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` and `locale/kz/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://mysite._:8000/kz
Using the URLconf defined in project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

i18n/
admin/
en/
^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, kz, didn't match any of these.

Comment: @alruadministrator Ok, I change the answer